# Implement idle time within my iphone App

Tags: iphone, timer

I'd like to implement a function within my App so that when a user doesn't use the App for 5 minutes the App runs from the start in stead of where the user left off.

I found the plist property 'Application doesn't run in background' but this function let the App always runs from the start. Is there a way that I can set a timer for this plist property or do something likewise in pseudo-code?

---

Update:

The ways which are mentioned are correct. However I'm searching for a solution which let the App notices the idle-time after the App has entered the background. (i.e. after pressing the home-button). Hope you can help me out

---

Solution:

I've found the solution. First I'm saving the NSDate within

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //save date
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSDate.date forKey:@"date"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Then when I'm returning inside the App I'm comparing the saved date to the actual date. If the timeinterval is larger then 5 minutes. The App goes to the password viewcontroller, which forces the user to login again!

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        //calculate difference in time
        NSDate *time = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"date"];

        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:time];

        if(timeInterval >= 300){

            Password *vc = [[Password alloc] init];
            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
            [vc release];

            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trigger a log out in one of my apps if the app is backgrounded for more than a certain amount of time.  To do this, I have the following methods in my application delegate.  Certain calls are dependent on my refactoring library, es_ios_utils(not really required), and code for my UserDefaults model is not included, but this should give you an idea:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    UserDefaults.instance.enteredBackgroundAt = NSDate.date;
}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if([UserDefaults.instance.enteredBackgroundAt dateByAddingMinutes:20].isPast)
        [self logOut];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If use is not touching on iPad when your app is running means he is not using your app right?

Then you can check for idle time follow this code below... (I am pasting this code from my blog post)

**Step 1 –** Add a class (IdleTimeCheck) in your project which subclass UIApplication. In the implementation file, override the sendEvent: method like so:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [super sendEvent:event];

    // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch or an Ended touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0) 
    {
        // allTouches count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
            [self resetIdleTimer];
    }
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer 
{
    if (idleTimer) {
        [idleTimer invalidate];
        [idleTimer release];
    }

    idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxIdleTime target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded {
    NSLog(@"idle time exceeded");
    //write logic to go to start page again
}
```

where maxIdleTime and idleTimer are instance variables.

**Step 2 –** Modify your UIApplicationMain function in main.m file to use your UIApplication subclass class as principal class.

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"IdleTimeCheck",nil);
```

see this post on my blog - http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/detecting-user-inactivityidle-time-since-last-touch-on-screen/